# Cordova firefoxos web access issue

Tags: networking, cordova, simulator

I'm trying to port my properly working (in iOS, Android) cordova app to Firefoxos.

The simulator starts properly and its browser can load web pages BUT my app cannot load data from the web.

Looking at console I see the following errors:

```
"JavaScript error: app://aa2a2c24-a8d6-447d-92da-4f2e9af65661/plugins/org.apache.cordova.network-information/src/firefoxos/NetworkProxy.js, line 33: missing : after property id" simulator-process.js:44
"JavaScript error: app://aa2a2c24-a8d6-447d-92da-4f2e9af65661/cordova.js, line 1120: Module org.apache.cordova.network-information.NetworkProxy does not exist."
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Cordova 3.5.0

Simulator FirfeoxOS 1.3 and FirfeoxOS 1.4

Answer (score 1):

After some research I figured out the issues

1- Despite upgrading cordova to 3.5.0 I must remember that plugins don't get automatically update.

To get the plugin code for firefoxos updated I added again the same plugin, removed the firefoxos platform and reinstalled it again.
At that point the javascript errors were gone

2- Then the ajax call were still not accessible due to permissions. To ensure you can have ajax call you have to put in your manifest.webapp the following code

```
 "type": "privileged",
  "permissions": {
    "systemXHR": { "description": "Required for AJAX calls in app"}
  }
```

Both "type" and "permissions" are needed

3- Finally you have to ensure the ajax calls use

```
mozSystem: true
```

Specifically for jquery, you could put something like the following on top of your js file:

```
 if (device.platform == 'firefoxos') { 
  $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options ) {
  if ( options.firefoxOS ) {
    options.xhr = function() {
      return new window.XMLHttpRequest( {
    mozSystem: true
      } );
    }
  }
} );

$.ajaxSetup( {
  firefoxOS: true
} );
```

}

Now I can properly handle ajax calls.